# How do I create condense list in Excel using formula (not VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to this site and haven't done much in Excel of decades (yes, decades), so I forgotten more than I know now.

Background: I am working on a simple pay sheet checking spreadsheet. One Worksheet is input timesheet for data entry, the complex one does all the calculations (Hourly rate; shift loading; tax formula, etc.) and the final worksheet presents the results in the same format as pay slip. Having finished the complex formulas in the calculation sheet, I am now stuck on condensing the results for the final results on the last sheet. I have try numerous functions including: vlookup, index, match, rank.eq, small and others, as per examples of other question on this site. Sample data is:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+--------------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
|    |                          A                          |       B        |     C      |      D       |   E    |   F    |  G  |   H    |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+--------------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
|  1 | Sample data:                                        |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
|  2 | Monday                                              | Ordinary Hours | 30/04/2018 | Day Shift    | 10.85  | 21.85  |   1 | 237.07 |
|  3 | Tuesday                                             | Ordinary Hours | 1/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  |   1 |        |
|  4 | Wednesday                                           | Ordinary Hours | 2/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  |   1 |        |
|  5 | Thursday                                            | Ordinary Hours | 3/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  |   1 |        |
|  6 | Friday                                              | Ordinary Hours | 4/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  |   1 |        |
|  7 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
|  8 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
|  9 | Monday                                              | Ordinary Hours | 7/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  |   1 |        |
| 10 | Tuesday                                             | Ordinary Hours | 8/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  |   1 |        |
| 11 | Wednesday                                           | Ordinary Hours | 9/05/2018  | Day Shift    | 10.85  | 21.85  |   1 | 237.07 |
| 12 | Thursday                                            | Ordinary Hours | 10/05/2018 | Day Shift    | 10.85  | 21.85  |   1 | 237.07 |
| 13 | Friday                                              | Ordinary Hours | 11/05/2018 |              |        | 21.85  |   1 |        |
| 14 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
| 15 | Monday                                              | Overtime 1.5   | 30/04/2018 |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 16 | Tuesday                                             | Overtime 1.5   | 1/05/2018  | Overtime 1.5 | 2      | 21.85  | 1.5 |  65.55 |
| 17 | Wednesday                                           | Overtime 1.5   | 2/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 18 | Thursday                                            | Overtime 1.5   | 3/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 19 | Friday                                              | Overtime 1.5   | 4/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 20 | Saturday                                            | Overtime 1.5   | 5/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 21 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
| 22 | Monday                                              | Overtime 1.5   | 7/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 23 | Tuesday                                             | Overtime 1.5   | 8/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 24 | Wednesday                                           | Overtime 1.5   | 9/05/2018  |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 25 | Thursday                                            | Overtime 1.5   | 10/05/2018 |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 26 | Friday                                              | Overtime 1.5   | 11/05/2018 |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 27 | Saturday                                            | Overtime 1.5   | 12/05/2018 |              |        | 21.85  | 1.5 |        |
| 28 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
| 29 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
| 30 | Required result on separate sheet in same workbook: |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
| 31 | Taxable Allowances                                  | Comments       | Qty        | Rate         | Factor | Amount |     |        |
| 32 | Ordinary Hours                                      | 30/04/2018     | 10.85      | 21.85        | 1      | 237.07 |     |        |
| 33 | Ordinary Hours                                      | 9/05/2018      | 10.85      | 21.85        | 1      | 237.07 |     |        |
| 34 | Ordinary Hours                                      | 10/05/2018     | 10.85      | 21.85        | 1      | 237.07 |     |        |
| 35 | Overtime 1.5                                        | 1/05/2018      | 2          | 21.85        | 1.5    | 65.55  |     |        |
| 36 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
| 37 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
| 38 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
| 39 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
| 40 |                                                     |                |            |              |        |        |     |        |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+--------------+--------+--------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: PivotTable should be useful, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: It's difficult to undestand your data. Could you copy/paste from Excel into https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ into the top box. Choose Header Location>>Spreadsheet and then paste the bottom box in here (formatting as code to preserve the fixed-width font). Then we can understand how these columns line up.

Comment: ygaft - Thank you for your comment. I refreshed my knowledge of PivotTables and it appears to me that my data is not suitable for a PivotTable. There are many blank cells and what I am trying to do is obtain the data from the rows that have data in columns  D & E. There could be multiple rows with the same data in column B, D & E not unique data as a PivotTable usually shows.

If I am wrong, I would appreciate being steered in the correct direction.

Thanks.